# Create Pie Chart using Jq plot with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, charts, jqplot

I use the following Function for create chart it was working Fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [
    ['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14], 
    ['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]
  ];
  var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data], 
    { 
      seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
        rendererOptions: {

          showDataLabels: true
        }
      }, 
      legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
});
```

And my problem is if I get the JSON in another array and i use that array into the pie chart it will not work.Which means...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var data1= new Array();
  data1=[['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14], 
    ['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]];

  var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data1], 
    { 
      seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
        rendererOptions: {

          showDataLabels: true
        }
      }, 
      legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: I can't see any problem in the code you've provided. Here's a fiddle I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/XBg5Z/1/ .Can you show us what JSON you're passing to the jqplot function?

Comment: @kayen in your fiddle the javascript doesn't show the chart

Comment: Err, I believe it's showing me 2 similar PIE charts, much similar to the one on the jqplot examples page.

Comment: not very clear what the problem is... same chart? need to explain your goals with this code. Except for a change of variable name, both seem identical but we have no way to know what you are wanting, or what the problem is

Comment: @kayen your fiddle is not working because reference to scripts are throwing 403 (forbidden) error. rest of your code is perfect. however, i tried this code by V.V myself and it is working fine.

Comment: Oh okay, I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XBg5Z/2/ . Added the files as resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, working fine.

```
 $.getJSON('/mcontraller/getvalues', function(data) {
        var items1 = new Array();
        var j=0;
        for ( var i in data ) {
            var items = new Array();
            items.push(i,Number(data[i]));
            items1[j++] = items;
        }

        var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', eval([items1]), {

                    seriesDefaults:{
                        // Make this a pie chart.
                        renderer:jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                        rendererOptions:{
                            // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                            // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                            dataLabels:'value',
                            showDataLabels:true
                        }
                    },
                    legend:{ show:true, location:'e' }
                }
        );

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The chart datas which are used for plotting charts are passed as strings and so i used eval to parse that as object and that works fine.
    `eval(data1)`

Answer (score 0):

i just tried your code myself. and it worked perfectly. i dont think there is any error. probably you should check reference to [jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js](http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js)